# How do i wrap a link into html ahref when sending email using Python

Tags: python, email, href

I am new to Python and i was trying to send an email using Python. When email is received, the email contains a long link and i was wondering if there is a way i could wrap the link into html ahref. Below is my code:

```
import csv
import datetime
import os
import smtplib
from email import message
from email.mime.text import MIMEText



import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/Amazon-Fire-TV-Stick-4K-Ultra-Hd-With-Alexa-Voice-Remote-Streaming-Media-Player/dp/B079QB9BD7/ref=sr_1_2_mod_primary_new?dchild=1&keywords=amazon+fire+stick&qid=1608568582&sbo=RZvfv%2F%2FHxDF%2BO5021pAnSA%3D%3D&sr=8-2'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'}


def check_stick_price():
    # this makes the request
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # this parses into html
    bs = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

   

    ## this gives  the product name by using 'productTitle' id - by adding .get_text() allows you to get display the text
    product_title = bs.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
    print(product_title.strip())

    # this gets the price by using 'priceblock_dealprice' id
    price = bs.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
    print(price)

#the following will input into CSV file
    file_exists = True

    if not os.path.exists("./price.csv"):
        file_exists = False

    with open("price.csv", "a") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
        fields = ["Timestamp", "Price"]
        if not file_exists:
            writer.writerow(fields)

        timestamp = f"{datetime.datetime.date(datetime.datetime.now())} , {datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now())}"
        writer.writerow([timestamp, price])
        print("wrote data to file")

    return price

# the following will send an email

def send_email():
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()

    server.login('example@gmail.com', 'password')

    subject = "Hey Price fell down"

    body = """\

       the price has gone down and to check
       <a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/Amazon-Fire-TV-Stick-4K-Ultra-Hd-With-Alexa-Voice-Remote-Streaming-Media-Player/dp/B079QB9BD7/ref=sr_1_2_mod_primary_new?dchild=1&keywords=amazon+fire+stick&qid=1608568582&sbo=RZvfv%2F%2FHxDF%2BO5021pAnSA%3D%3D&sr=8-2">click here </a> 
       and enjoy your product
        """
    msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n\n"
    html_Part = MIMEText(body, "html")
    server.sendmail('example@gmail.com', 'example@gmail.com', msg , html_Part)
    print("Email is Sent")
    server.quit()


# this does a comparison and should trigger if the price goes down
price = check_stick_price()
compare = str("£50.00")
if (price < compare):
  send_email()
```

The body of the email received looks like:

```
   the price has gone down and to check
   <a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/Amazon-Fire-TV-Stick-4K-Ultra-Hd-With-Alexa-Voice-Remote-Streaming-Media-Player/dp/B079QB9BD7/ref=sr_1_2_mod_primary_new?dchild=1&keywords=amazon+fire+stick&qid=1608568582&sbo=RZvfv%2F%2FHxDF%2BO5021pAnSA%3D%3D&sr=8-2">click here </a>
   and enjoy your product
```

I was looking to make it look like [click here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Amazon-Fire-TV-Stick-4K-Ultra-Hd-With-Alexa-Voice-Remote-Streaming-Media-Player/dp/B079QB9BD7/ref=sr_1_2_mod_primary_new?dchild=1&keywords=amazon%20fire%20stick&qid=1608568582&sbo=RZvfv%2F%2FHxDF%2BO5021pAnSA%3D%3D&sr=8-2)

Comment: Try to print out the header of your email. It seems the mail is not viewed as an HTML email.

Comment: @SébastienBémelmans would you mind elaborating your suggestion more?